# Page doesn't work good in JavaScript code with form

Tags: javascript, html

I write this (the full code) code at JavaScript.

In line 6 I wrote the code:

```
div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit="+ return refresh(name, url, document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh'); +" method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
```

When I add this code, the page didn't work good.

I believe that I have a problem with the quotes of `onsubmit`, because when I delete the ' onsubmit'  everything works good.

If I write the full code in regular HTML (not in JS) everything works good.

What should I do to solve the problem?

The full code:

```
function chat(mem_id) {
    count++;
    var div_new = "<div style='position:absolute; width:200px; bottom:0px; left:10px;'>";
        div_new = div_new+"<div style='width:100%; background-color:green;'>top "+ mem_id +" - "+count+"</div>";
        div_new = div_new+"<div style='width:100%; height:300px; background-color:pink;'>bottom // refresh_chat"+ mem_id +" ";
    var name = "send_chat_"+mem_id;
    var url = "send_chat.php";
        div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit="+ return refresh(name, url, document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh'); +" method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
        div_new = div_new+"<textarea name='"+name+"' autofocus=autofocus placeholder='"+name+"'></textarea><input type=submit value=' send '>";
        div_new = div_new+"</form>";
        div_new = div_new+"</div>";
        div_new = div_new+"</div>";
    bottom = div_new;
    document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/xtCq9/4/)

there are several mistakes in this line

```
div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit="+ return refresh(name, url, document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh'); +" method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
```

Use this code

```
function chat(mem_id) {
    count++;
    var div_new = "<div style='position:absolute; width:200px; bottom:0px; left:10px;'>";
        div_new = div_new+"<div style='width:100%; background-color:green;'>top "+ mem_id +" - "+count+"</div>";
        div_new = div_new+"<div style='width:100%; height:300px; background-color:pink;'>bottom // refresh_chat"+ mem_id +" ";
    var name = "send_chat_"+mem_id;
    var url = "send_chat.php";
        div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit=\"return refresh(" + name +","+ url+",document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh');\" + method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
        div_new = div_new+"<textarea name='"+name+"' autofocus=autofocus placeholder='"+name+"'></textarea><input type=submit value=' send '>";
        div_new = div_new+"</form>";
        div_new = div_new+"</div>";
        div_new = div_new+"</div>";
    bottom = div_new;
    document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = bottom;
}
```

The main issue is because of return is not part of string because of double quote , He need to use escape sequence

This is correct solution

```
div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit=\"return refresh(" + name +","+ url+",document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh');\" + method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
```

I also added the same escape sequence here

Comment: Can you also point out  the problems rather than just provide the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the problem is the quotes. When you write `onsubmit="`, the final `"` is closing the string that you started at `div_new+`. The solution is to [*escape* the quote character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings). JavaScript lets you do this with the `\` character: `\"`. So this is what the line should be:

```
div_new = div_new+"<form name='"+name+"' onsubmit=\"+ return refresh(name, url, document.forms[name][name].value , '', '', 'refresh'); +\" method='post' style='display:inline;'>";
```